# Give a specific value to a variable based on url content

Tags: javascript

I have a site with a core domain with something like this:

```
www.example.com/de-e
www.example.com/us-e
```

If I start the navigation to site and go to different pages I have urls like this:

```
www.example.com/de-e/contact-us
```

I want to store give to a variable named vde the value de if the url have the value de-e and us if the url have the value us-e.With JQuery I could possible use the contains() with simple JS how can I make it?

Comment: Will the first part of the path always be a language?Will you cater for more than 2 languages now or in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var vde;
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/de-e") == 0) {
  vde = "de";
} else if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/us-e") == 0) {
  vde = "us";
} else {
  // set default value or handle error, e.g.
  alert("Neither US nor DE.");
}
```

Comment: Because you have check, if the `pathname` **starts** with the `/de-e` (or `/us/e`) string. The `... > -1` would check the presence of the string **anywhere** in the `pathname`, not just at the start.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
      var url = window.location.href ;
      if(url.indexOf("us-e") > -1)
         {
                vde =us
         }
      else
          {      vde=de
          }
```

index of can be used in place of contains, if its greater than 0 it has the string.

Comment: This condition is true for `www.example.com/de-e/foo/bar/us-e` or `www.example.com/foo/bar/us-e/acme`, not only for `www.example.com/us-e/anything/else`.

Comment: thanks a lot for review/suggestion,your answer is correct, My main concern was giving him alternative to Contains in javascript :)